# How to debug Adobe process from adobe workbench ES2 tool

Tags: adobe, livecycle, workbench, livecycle-designer

I am finding issue with adobe service invocation
i have invoked process from workbench and recorded the process.

process recording is not showing any error, document is also generated at specified path, but it is not giving sucess message. :(

i stucked into this issue.

in normal scenario we get sucess message in dialog , but in my case i am able to create document but sucess message is not comming

please help..

Comment: Can you provide more details about the purpose of your application and how's being used?

Comment: In my application we use adobe service to create contract documents. we have set of templates ready which are binded to xml schema, from java code we generate xml data and invoke the adobe service using Adobe Livecycle client. we supply data in xml form along with some process variables such as output path etc. in my service i am having output variable as generated documents path. after successfull invocation of service , output path is shown but in my case this was not comming.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're invoking Output service. If so, be sure to follow the guidelines described here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/9.0/programLC/help/000674.html

Also you should post the code you're executing to get a broader sense of what you're trying to achieve.